# Making a macro in excel to highlight cells that are bigger than a control cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that highlights a specific cel in the row if it is greater than the control value. My excel sheet looks as follows:

[image: So for product A E2 needs to get a red color]

So for product A E2 needs to get a red color. Because its bigger than the value in cell K2. For product B the cells E and H need to get the color red because they are bigger than K3. Product C wont get any colors. This sheet is only an example. In the final sheet there will be more than 700 products, so the amount of rows needs  to be adjustable.

I think I need some kind of loop but have no idea how to set it up.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

J Rommers

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting? You don't need a macro for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using "conditional formatting" rules for smaller case scenarios.
Select the cell you want the rule to be applied, click "new rule" select "format only cells that contain" and then "cell value greater than K5" for example and select the desired cell formating.
This can be copied to other cells as well and changed per case basis.

Comment: Use @George advice, I just came in to write the same response.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly easy task and you could have easily done it by searching and trying something out.

But here's the code:

```
Dim sheetName As String
Dim startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer, endCol As Integer
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

sheetName = "Sheet1" 'Your sheetname

With Sheets(sheetName)

    startRow = 2 'start row for the loop
    startCol = 2 'start column for the loop

    endRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row 'Last Used Row
    endCol = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column 'Last Used Column

    For row = startRow To endRow Step 1 'Loop through rows

        For col = startCol To endCol - 1 Step 1 'Loop through columns | Leave out the Peak Column

            If .Cells(row, col).Value > .Cells(row, endCol).Value Then 'If value of cell is bigger than peak column

                .Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = vbRed 'mark cell in red
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
End With
```